# Complicated MySql Update Join Query

Tags: mysql, join

Have is an example of the problem I'm facing. The database tables are a little different than usual, but needed to be setup this way.

Items: id, order_id, other fields

Items_Drinks: id, drinks, other fields

Orders: id, other fields

Orders_Drinks: id, drinks, other fields

I need to have an update query that will update the Orders_Drinks table with the sum of the Items_Drinks drinks field that have the same order_id as Orders_Drinks id field.

```
Items: 1   1   ...
Items: 2   1   ...
Items_Drinks: 1   4   ...
Items_Drinks: 2   5   ...

Orders: 1   ...
Orders_Drinks: 1   9   ...
```

The Orders_Drinks is currently correct, but if I were to update Items_Drinks with id of 1 to 5, I would need an update command to get Orders_Drinks with id 1 to equal 10.

It would be best if the command would update every record of the Orders_Drinks.

I know my database is not typical, but it is needed for my application. This is because the Drinks table is not needed for all entries. The Drinks table has over 5000 fields in it, so if every record had these details the database would grow and slow for no real reason. Please do not tell me to restructure the database, this is needed.

I am currently using for loops in my C# program to do what I need, but having 1 command would save a ton of time!

Here is my best attempt, but it gives an error of "invalid group function".

```
update Orders_Drinks join Items on Items.order_id=Orders_Drinks.id join Items_Drinks on Items_Drinks.id=Items.id set Orders_Drinks.drinks=sum(Item_Drinks.drinks);
```

Comment: A table with 5000 fields?  Sounds like the schema as a whole needs to be re-thought.  I know you said in your question that "it has to be this way", but my guess is that it doesn't have to be that way.  Perhaps relational storage is not what you really need, if you in essence need something that is schema-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're wanting.

Edited:

```
UPDATE `Order_Drinks` a 
SET a.`drinks` = (SELECT SUM(b.`drinks`) FROM `Items_Drinks` b INNER JOIN `Items` c ON (b.`id` = c.`id`) WHERE a.`id` = c.`order_id`)
```

That should give you a total of 9 for the Order_Drinks table for the row id of 1.

This is assuming that Orders.id == Orders_Drinks.id and that Items.id == Items_Drinks.id.

Comment: This only gets the results of 1 of the item_drinks records, it does not sum them. Must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an aggregation.  You can do this in the `join` part of the `update` statement:

```
update Orders_Drinks od join
       (select i.order_id, sum(id.drinks) as sumdrinks
        from Items i join
             Items_Drinks id
             on id.id = i.id
       ) iid
       on iid.order_id = od.id
    set od.drinks = iid.sumdrinks;
```

Comment: This is a much more efficient way of doing this for sure.

Comment: @Nate . . . Why do you think this is not particularly efficient?  Under many circumstances, its performance will be comparable to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will return the `id` from the `orders_drinks` table, along with the current value of the `drinks` summary field, and a new summary value derived from the related `items_drinks` tables.

(Absent the name of the foreign key column, I've assumed the foreign key column names are of the pattern: "referenced_table_id" )

```
SELECT od.id
     , od.drinks               AS old_drinks
     , IFNULL(td.tot_drinks,0) AS new_drinks
  FROM orders_drinks od
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT di.orders_drinks_id
              , SUM(di.drinks) AS tot_drinks 
           FROM items_drinks di
          GROUP BY di.orders_drinks_id
       ) td
    ON td.orders_drinks_id = od.id
```

Once we have SELECT query written that gets the result we want, we can change it into an UPDATE statement.  Just replace `SELECT ... FROM` with the `UPDATE` keyword, and add a `SET` clause, to assign/replace the value to the `drinks` column.

e.g.

```
UPDATE orders_drinks od
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT di.orders_drinks_id
              , SUM(di.drinks) AS tot_drinks 
           FROM items_drinks di
          GROUP BY di.orders_drinks_id
       ) td
    ON td.orders_drinks_id = od.id
   SET od.drinks = IFNULL(td.tot_drinks,0)
```

(NOTE: the IFNULL function is optional. I just used it to substitute a value of zero whenever there are no matching rows in `items_drinks` found, or whenever the total is NULL.)

This will update all rows (that need to be updated) in the `orders_drinks` table. A `WHERE` clause could be added (after the `SET` clause), if you only wanted to update particular rows in `orders_drinks`, rather than all rows:

```
 WHERE od.id = 1
```

Again, to get to this, first get a SELECT statement working to return the new value to be assigned to the column, along with the key of the table to be updated. Once that is working, convert it into an UPDATE statement, moving the expression that returns the new value down to a SET clause.